# Java EE Servlet rewrite servlet path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, java-ee-6

I have a simple user application. I have a `MainController` Servlet that will be in charge of general interaction in the application. This servlet will be "listening" for url-patterns: **/, /index, etc** (any other form of index). I also have an `UserController` Servlet that is in charge of login among other things, this one "listens" from `/CheckLogin` url-pattern.

I have form in a jsp, in the url `/`, that when I submit it, it points to the servlet at `/CheckLogin`. Then `UserController` servlet process it and either the login is ok or wrong it redirect to `/` (the `MainController` will be in charge of determining the page to show depending if the user logged in or not).

All work flawlessly except that after submitting the first time, then the form page has url `/CheckLogin`. I would like to remove it and show only / (even if logged or not). How do I do this (plain Java EE, not Spring or any other framework)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you do a *forward* instead of a *redirect*, the URL on the client browser will not be updated: [RequestDispatcher#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29); an explanation can be found at [Forward vs Redirect](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).

In addition, it might be a better idea to implement authentication as a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) instead of a Servlet; that way, the Filter can be used to intercept any URL you deem needs to be secured.

Is there a specific reason you're not using a web framework? They're meant to take care of things security and routing for you, generally.

Comment: well I'm trying to learn a little bit more of java ee itself before going for a framework. I'm currently doing forward of the request. But the form has the CheckLogin pointed :S also, do you have a good link to learn a bit more about filters?

Comment: Since you are not going with Frameworks, go with patterns, they will give a good foundation before getting into frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications

Comment: More about filters: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

This SO question talks a bit about using filters for authentication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984984/authorization-using-filters-in-java-ee

So are you saying that you're forwarding, but the "/CheckLogin" URL is still appearing in the browser?